# Can I use transpose functionality in oracle to achieve this?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have written a view which gives me the following output

```
Vessel Name ETA
XYZ    1-Jul-12
XYZ    2-Jul-12
XYZ    3-Jul-12
XYZ    4-Jul-12
XYZ    5-Jul-12
XYZ    6-Jul-12
XYZ    7-Jul-12
```

Actually I would like to get an output like the below

```
Vessel Name    ETA_1    ETA_2        ETA_3
XYZ           1-Jul-12  2-Jul-12    3-Jul-12
XYZ           2-Jul-12  3-Jul-12    4-Jul-12
XYZ           3-Jul-12  4-Jul-12    5-Jul-12
XYZ           4-Jul-12  5-Jul-12    6-Jul-12
XYZ           5-Jul-12  6-Jul-12    7-Jul-12
```

There could be any no of vessels available. And there could be any no of ETAs for that vessel not just 5 rows.

Why Three etas? A vessel sails from Port A on 01-jul then this would be ETA_FROM date and to Port B on 02-Jul then this would be ETA_VIA and to Port C on 03-Jul then this would be ETA_TO. Then again it sails from Port C to D on 04-Jul-2012 on 05-Jul then In this case, the ETA_FROM would be 02-Jul and ETA_VIA would be 03-Jul and ETA_TO should be 4-Jul. The least of the three eta would be the ETA_FROM date and next higher would be ETA_VIA date and next higher would ETA_TO date.

EDIT: I tried this, but the performance is poor:

```
select t1.vessel_name,
       t1.eta ETA_FROM ,
       t2.eta ETA_VIA , 
       t3.eta ETA_TO 
from 
  test t1,
  test t2, 
  test t3 
where t1.eta<t2.eta and 
      t3.eta>t2.eta and 
      t1.eta=(select max(test.eta) 
              from test 
              where test.eta<t2.eta) 
      and t3.eta= (select min(test.eta) 
                   from test 
                   where test.eta>t2.eta)
```

Comment: please improve the example. Add another vessel. Explain the rules. Why there are exactly 5 rows in the output? Why three ETAs?

Comment: There could be any no of vessels available. And there could be any no of ETAs for that vessel not just 5 rows.

Comment: in the input are 7 rows, in the output are 5. Why 5? why not 4?

Comment: There could be any no of vessels available. And there could be any no of ETAs for that vessel not just 5 rows. 
Why Three etas?
A vessel sails from Port A on 01-jul then this would be ETA_FROM date and to Port B on 02-Jul then this wuold be ETA_VIA and to Port C on 03-Jul then this would be ETA_TO.

Then again it sails from Port C to D on 04-Jul-2012 on 05- Jul then 
In this case, the ETA_FROM would be 02-Jul and ETA_VIA would be 03-Jul and ETA_TO should be 4-Jul.

The least of the three eta would be the ETA_FROM date and next higher would be ETA_VIA date and next higher would ETA_TO date.

Comment: Now, this is an explanation. The data itself makes no sense :) I will add it to the question.

Comment: Thanks Florin. I have written a query to achieve this result.select 
t1.vessel_name,t1.eta ETA_FROM ,t2.eta ETA_VIA , t3.eta ETA_TO
 from test t1,test t2, test t3

where t1.eta<t2.eta and t3.eta>t2.eta

and t1.eta=(select max(test.eta) from test
where test.eta<t2.eta)

and t3.eta=
(select min(test.eta) from test
where test.eta>t2.eta)

But this doesn't work for huge data.

Answer (score 3):

```
select 
    * 
from (
    select 
        vessel, 
        eta, 
        lead(eta) over (order by eta) as eta2,
        lead(port) over (order by eta) as port2,
        lead(eta,2) over (order by eta) as eta3,
        lead(port,2) over (order by eta) as port3
    from your_view
)
where 
     eta3 is not null;
```

Comment: Thank you so much  florin. It perfectly worked worked :). I have one more doubt. Actually the table has port and etd as well. I need the port and ETD for this eta. Is it possile?

The vessel's ETA at Port A is  01-Jul and ETD from Port A is 02-Jul.  So can I get the corresponding info as well?

Comment: Hi Florin. Thank you so much. Was struggling with this query. You made it within  a second. Thanks